# How to fetch records according to largest first

Tags: sql

How to fetch records according to largest first?

**Example**

```
 SELECT  marks FROM  students 

 marks 

  50
  20
  80
  65
  35
```

**But I want to fetch details according to highest marks like this**

Marks

```
 80
 65
 50
 35
 20
```

Comment: `ORDER BY marks DESC`

Comment: Did you try anything? This is pretty straightforward, IMHO.

Comment: <?php
    session_start(); 
    $db = mysqli_connect('localhost:XXXX', 'root', 'xxxxxx', 'db_name');
    if ($db->connect_errno) {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . $db->connect_error;
        exit();
    } 
 $query = "SELECT * FROM `students` ORDER BY `students`.`marks` DESC";
   echo $query;
   $results = mysqli_query($db, $query);
    
    
    ?>

Comment: Please do not dump code in comments. Code posted this way is unreadable. Edit your original question to add any new information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should just user `ORDER BY` the column you want and `ASC` or `DESC` for ascending or descending ordering

```
SELECT  marks FROM  students ORDER BY marks DESC
```

Comment: *"and ASC or DESC"* - I'd take that out IMHO. The OP specifically states: *"but i want to fetch details according to highest marks like this `<code>`"*

Comment: Please don't post answers on obviously off topic/bad questions! [See: **Should one advise on off topic questions?**](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/276572)